# Animate text color in Android Lollipop transition

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, shared-element-transition, activity-transition

We're trying to make a transition to move a TextView of one Activity to another TextView of another Activity. The common awesome Android Lollipop transition, to animate shared views.

In our scenario, the first TextView is white, and the second one is red. It also has different sizes.

[image: The transition with shared views]

The issue we're having is that, if we look to the animation closely and with the phone in slow motion animations, we can see as the white TextView doesn't do any animation. Instead of that, the red TextView borns over the white one and then it's animated to the final position.

What we want to achieve is to fade out the white TextView while it's moving to the red one, and fade in the red one from the white TextView, also animating it. Well... you know, doing an incredible effect :·)

To achieve it, we're using the  transition in the theme definition:

```
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@transition/auto_transition</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@transition/auto_transition</item>
```

And, in our auto_transition.xml file:

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <autoTransition/>
</transitionSet>
```

But, for sure, it's not the way the Android guys want it to work.

If someone have any insight, it will be really appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up finding a better solution?

Comment: @Iage bad news there... nope.